# How to search hidden buffer during insert-mode completion?

Tags: buffers, ins-completion, hidden-buffers

I am trying to write a completion function which has as its source a 386k line (CSS) file.

Initially I read the file into a list with `readfile()` and used a `for` loop to iterate over each line, matching it against the base text.  This worked but took about 5-7 seconds.  (`readfile()` was very quick; the time was spent in the loop.)

I couldn't see a way to speed that up so instead I tried loading the file into a buffer and using `search()` to find the matches.  I coded it up with a hardcoded string pattern and it was very fast - a few hundred milliseconds at most.

So then I tried using that in my completion function but ran into a problem.  To search the big file I switch to its buffer, do the search stuff, then switch back to the previous buffer.  But during insert-mode completion it is not allowed to switch buffers.

Is there a way to run commands or a function in a hidden buffer without switching to it?

Comment: Seeing your actual code would help but, from your description, I am wondering if using a `:for` loop wouldn't be the cause of your problems. Would `:help filter()` be better?

Comment: The difficulty with `filter()` is that I want to match CSS class names and also extract the properties for those class names.  That's tricky with `filter()`.

Comment: I just tried pre-processing the file into a dictionary and then when autocompleting looping over they dictionary's keys looking for matches.  It's fast enough (although the one-off pre-processing still takes 5-7 seconds).

Comment: @romainl I'm now pre-converting the file to JSON and `json_decode()`-ing it in Vim which is very fast.  For searching I'm using `filter()`, as you suggested, on the keys and it is fast.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool. You should consider posting your solution (or a minimal version of your solution) as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I sped this up by pre-converting the CSS file to JSON.  Vim is fast at reading and decoding JSON:

```
let css = readfile('myfile.json')->join('')->json_decode()
```

To search for keys matching a prefix, I did this:

```
let keys = keys(css)
        \ ->filter({_, v -> stridx(v, prefix) == 0})
        \ ->sort()
```